# How to Add Rules to align views inside Cardview in Android

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I have a cardview  inside which I have several Views which I want to align one below another. For a relative layout I will use the following

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idofanotherview);
```

However I cannot find addRule() method for cardview, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) of the CardView states, this component inherits from FrameLayout. That is normal that the `addRule()` method is unrecognized.

If you really need to use a RelativeLayout to position your subviews then I suggest that you wrap your subviews with one.

This [post](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156) gives you a good exemple of how to achieve what you need

Good luck!